# C - Popping last item from linked lists

Tags: c, list, pointers, structure

I am learning linked lists and they are causing me a lot of troubles.
I am calling the function with this call:

```
pop(&list);
```

ANd here's the code:

```
void pop(NODE** first) {
if(*first != NULL && first!= NULL){
    NODE* ptr = *first;
    while(ptr->next->next != NULL){
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    free(ptr->next);
    ptr->next = NULL;   
}
```

It's also causing memory leak error even if I call it single time..

When calling this function multiple times, there are more memory leak errors.

Thanks in advance, Mimpopo.

EDIT: Definition of NODE

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;
```

The full CODE:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;



NODE* insert(NODE *first, int n){
    // create new node
    NODE* new = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    new->data = n;
    new->next = NULL;

    // if first is NULL, this will be the first
    if(first == NULL)
        return new;

     // otherwise, place it correctly
     NODE* ptr = first;

     // check inserting at the begining
     if(ptr->data > new->data){
        new->next = ptr;
        return new;
     }

     // insert in the middle
     while(ptr->next != NULL){
        if(ptr->next->data > n && ptr->data < n){
            new->next = ptr->next;
            ptr->next = new;
            break;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
     }

     // insert at the end of list
     if(ptr->next == NULL){
         ptr->next = new;
     }

    return first;
}

void traverse(NODE *first){
    NODE* ptr = first;
    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }   
}   

NODE* search(NODE *first, int n){
    NODE* ptr = first;
    while(ptr != NULL){
        if(ptr->data == n){
            printf("FOUND %d\n!", n);
            return ptr;
        }
    ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    NODE* first = NULL;
    NODE* this = NULL;
    first = insert(first, 7);
    first = insert(first, 10);
    first = insert(first, 11);
    first = insert(first, 1);
    first = insert(first, 3);
    first = insert(first, 5);
    first = insert(first, 22);
    first = insert(first, 23);
    first = insert(first, 24);
    first = insert(first, 125);

    pop(&first);




}
```

Comment: Please add to your question the declaration of `NODE`, and the code which is calling `pop`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "memory leak error"?

Comment: One problem I see is that if `first` only contains one record, `while(ptr->next->next != NULL)` will cause a seg fault.

Comment: `ptr->next->next` is *always* wrong when you have not checked `ptr->next` for `NULL`. NB you have posted two different `pop()` functions.

Comment: `*first != NULL && first!= NULL` should be the other way around. You'd access `first` even if it was `NULL`.

Comment: No need to cast the result of `malloc`, that is done implicitly. Therefore `NODE* new = malloc(sizeof(NODE));` should be enough. Btw. you might want to avoid `new` as name to make it also compatible with c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not looked through all your code but as for the function then it can be written the following way

```
void pop( NODE ** first ) 
{
    if ( *first != NULL )
    {
        NODE *prev = NULL;
        NODE *current = *first;

        while ( current->next ) 
        {
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
        }

        if ( prev != NULL ) prev->next = current->next;
        else ( *first = NULL );

        free( current );
    }
}
```

As for your function implementation then it contains many errors. For example in this statement

```
if(*first != NULL && first!= NULL){
```

you shall swap the first and the second comparisons. That is the condition shall look like

```
if(first != NULL && *first!= NULL){
```

In this statement

```
while(ptr->next->next != NULL){
```

You have to be sure that `ptr->next`is not equal to NULL.

Also you do not check whether the deleted node is the first node of the list.

Take into account that function insert is also wrong. You consider only one condition in this code snippet

```
 while(ptr->next != NULL){
    if(ptr->next->data > n && ptr->data < n){
        new->next = ptr->next;
        ptr->next = new;
        break;
    }
    ptr = ptr->next;
 }
```

However it can be that for example

```
    ptr->next->data >= n && ptr->data < n
```

or

```
    ptr->next->data > n && ptr->data <= n
```

Comment: In my code:==3377== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3377==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==3377==    indirectly lost: 64 bytes in 8 blocks
==3377==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3377==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3377==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

Comment: If I may ask, what should I do if the delened node would be the first node of the list?

Comment: @Mestralx You asked about poping the last node. I showed you how the function can be written correctly.  So I do not understand "this does not work for me". What is wrong with the function I showed?

Comment: @Mestralx You have to delete the first node and set *first to NULL. I mean the case when the first node is the only one node in the list.

Comment: Your function still gives me ==3540== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3540==    definitely lost: 7 bytes in 1 blocks

Comment: Thank you very much. Cant rep you up.